# Hyperledger Fabric with docker not storing data after restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I setup Hyperledger Fabric V0.6 with docker image. I wrote small chain code program and perform some operations. Data is getting stored and fetched on request from Hyperledger blockchain.

I restart my chaincode program and data still persist. Ofcouse this should be expected behaviour.

But when I stop my Hyperledger fabric with command docker-compose down and start it again with docker-compose start and then start my chaincode program, I found that the whole data which was written before restart is gone. I couldn't find any data in my blockchain.

How can I avoid this behaviour of Hyperledger? I am running it on single peer/node. With multiple peers, if one of the peer restarted, then data/transactions from other peers get copied on it. But consider a worst scenario when all peers down. Does that mean we loose all our data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)  `docker-compose down` stops and **removes** all containers listed in docker-compose file *along* with their volumes (unless specified as external, have a look into the documentation).

You may want to stop the containers with `docker-compose stop` - this way after `docker-compose up` their data will be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

## [A Note on Data Persistence](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html)

If data persistence is desired on the peer container or the CouchDB container, one option is to mount a directory in the docker-host into a relevant directory in the container. For example, you may add the following two lines in the peer container specification in the `docker-compose-base.yaml` file:

`volumes:
 - /var/hyperledger/peer0:/var/hyperledger/production`

For the CouchDB container, you may add the following two lines in the CouchDB container specification:

`volumes:
 - /var/hyperledger/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data`